# Xcode cannot clone project from github

Tags: xcode, github, cloning

I just started using GitHub today. Why this is happening?
I used `http` request
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect your GitHub account to Xcode and then select a project to clone... If something goes wrong, you need to reinstall Xcode.